# JS Closure Compiler, @param syntax for array destructuring?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-closure-compiler, destructuring

I'm unable to find the correct syntax for `@param` annotations for array destructuring. E.g.:

```
let destructArray = ([one, two]) => one + two;
```

I tried imitating the object destructuring syntax:

```
// object destructuring works
/** @param {{one: number, two: number}} o */
let destructObject = ({one, two}) => one + two;

// array destructuring does not works
/** @param {[one: number, two: number]} a */
let destructArray = ([one, two]) => one + two;
```

But that's not valid syntax. I've also tried `/** @param {Array<number>} a */`, but then it expects a single parameter named `a`, not `one` and `two`.

Does anyone know the correct syntax to use for array destructuring?

Comment: **For others who, like me, hoped JSDoc's destructuring support would solve this**, it appears not. I answered hoping it would (you can see the answer here: https://pastebin.com/dNgVLCMd), but the OP said it didn't work. (Thanks for letting me know, junvar, and good luck -- it may be that CC doesn't support this yet.)

Comment: Your answer was still helpful in providing background; thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closure Compiler does not currently support different types at different array indexes. So in this case, all you do is:

```
/** @type {function(!Array<number>):number} */
let destructArray = ([one, two]) => one + two;
```